# Convert Variable to JSON Value Name

Tags: javascript, json

I have a variable like

`var column = $(this).attr('class');`

I then need to add this variable as the name of a JSON object like so

`obj.push({ column : anotherVar });`

This outputs "column" instead of my variable. What is the easiest way to convert my variable into a usable string in JSON.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to do it in two steps:

```
var tmp = {}; tmp[column] = anotherVar;
obj.push(tmp);
```

You can always use `[]` to refer to object properties whose names are dynamic, but you can't use such names in an object literal.